# How to connect Hbase With JDBC driver of Apache Drill programmatically

Tags: jdbc, hbase, apache-drill

I tried to use JDBC driver of Apache [Drill](https://drill.apache.org) programatically.

Here's the code:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager

object SearchHbaseWithHbase {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Class.forName("org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver")
    val zkIp = "192.168.3.2:2181"
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(s"jdbc:drill:zk=${zkIp};schema:hbase")
    connection.setSchema("hbase")

    println(connection.getSchema)
    val st = connection.createStatement()
    val rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Label")
    while (rs.next()){
      println(rs.getString(1))
    }
  }
}
```

I have set the database schema with type : hbase, Like:

```
connection.setSchema("hbase")
```

But it fails with the error code:

---

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: VALIDATION ERROR:
>   From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 19: Table 'Label' not found
>   SQL Query null

---

The Label table is exactly exit in my hbase. 
I can find My data when I use sqline like:

```
sqline -u jdbc:drill:zk.... 
use hbase;
input :select * from Label;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I confused the drill's schema and jdbc driver schema......
the correct codes should be like:

```
 object SearchHbaseWithHbase{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    Class.forName("org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver")
    val zkIp = "192.168.3.2:2181"
    val p = new java.util.Properties
    p.setProperty("schema","hbase")

//    val connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo
    val url = s"jdbc:drill:zk=${zkIp}"
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, p)
//    connection.setSchema("hbase")
//    println(connection.getSchema)
    val st = connection.createStatement()
    val rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Label")
    while (rs.next()){
      println(rs.getString(1))
    }
  }
}
```